# Ionic 3, angular 5 - cache problem with webapp

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, caching, web-applications

We have a Web-App (We build for browser platform) and our users get to it using their browsers on the mobile (this is a fall-back for thos who don't want to use the App itself).

We have many times (not always and only for several users) that after a big change in the code, those users can't use the application properly as the files are not updating until they are clearing their browser's cache.

We have tried several solutions to "force" the client to reload the updated file from the server with no luck.

We tried setting no-cahce to our nginx configuration.
Tried adding timestamp to index files.
Tried setting up custom Service workers.
So far, still we encounter some users that until they clear their cache, it doesn't work properly.

Any suggestions? Is there a way to force the client to re-download the updated files after an update?
Is there a way to change ionic build settings to include a timestamp or something like that to all the generated files?

Thanks :)

Comment: hope, u r using ng build --prod --aot. this will enable hashing to the script files. For index.html, we need to set no-cache headers in the API response

Comment: Indeed.We run "ionic cordova build browser --prod", still, the files are cached and some users can't seem to see the changes until they empty their cache :(

Comment: The HTML files btw, update fine. the problem is with the .js files in the build.

Comment: if you use ng build --prod --aot. it won't cache bcz the file name will be unique.

Comment: I know this is how it should work, yet we keep encounter situations where the caching happens and only after clearing cache we see the changes.

Comment: The issue is that the file names are not unique. they are the same as the other builds

Comment: what is the Angular CLI version you are using?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the responses. I managed to do this evantually using WebPacks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I Managed to solve the issue.
The solution was adding a hash to the pages files generate by ionic build.

This row needs to be added to the top of the webpack.js file:

```
var useDefaultConfig = require('@ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config.js');
```

And then in the module.exports function add the following:

```
useDefaultConfig.prod.output['chunkFilename'] = "[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js";
```

This causes the files generated to be hashed differently on every build.

Comment: Do you can provide a link or tutorial about this?

Answer (score 0):

As an expansion to @S.Moran's answer (which is great , thanks!) I did this;

Create a /src/config/webpack.config.js file like this;

```
var path = require('path');
var useDefaultConfig = require('@ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config.js');
var useDefaultConfig = require('@ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config.js');
module.exports = function () {
    console.log("Custom webpack.config");
    useDefaultConfig.prod.output['chunkFilename'] = "[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js";
   return useDefaultConfig;
}
```

Then have this in my *package.json*

```
"config": {
    "ionic_webpack": "./src/config/webpack.config.js"
},
```